# Java code does not recognize ctrl-m(^M) but works fine for other ctrl-characters(^Q,^A,^T etc) Linux

Tags: java, linux, control-characters

I have a requirement where I need to remove two specific control characters: `^@` and `^M`, from the incoming data in Java on a Linux box.

Below mentioned parts work as expected:

```
String s;
s = s.replaceAll("\\x00","as");
s = s.replaceAll("\\000", "as");
```

but these don't:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\015", "as"); //Octal
s = s.replaceAll("\\x0D", "as"); //Hex
```

I have tried all available representations(octal/hex/unicode) including `\r` to represent `^M` in my code but it does not work. As mentioned above everything works fine for other control characters.

Please suggest if there's anything that I haven't tried or missed.

Edit: Providing the implementable code as requested.

```
public class sampSC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./samp1.txt"));

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            String s = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s.replaceAll("\\00", "sb"); //works
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s.replaceAll("\\x11", "s23b"); //works
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s.replaceAll("\\r$", "aa"); //doesn't work
            System.out.println(s);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `\r` instead of `^M`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: " all available representations(octal/hex/unicode) including \r to represent ^M" --Done that... Doesn't work.

Comment: `string s = s.replaceAll("\\013", "as");` is nonsense regardless. Since you're declaring `s` on that line. And Java doesn't have a type `string`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: mixed up decimal and octal representation. corrected.

Comment: Code looks alright. How did you verify that there is a \r in the string at all?

Comment: "cat -vet" gives special characters as well. In my file there are two ^@ and ^M. Both of which need to be replaced.

Comment: And you don't read, by any chance, with `readLine`.

Comment: Not readline, it was read using BufferedReader though. Is there any problem with using BufferedReader class?

Comment: Show us a complete program (a [mcve], preferably).

Comment: @Harald: just checked my code, I am using readLine under bufferedreader. Can you explain how it affects the execution? 
Should I instead use chararray here, however I believe it'll dampen the performance as I intend to execute this on large files. Is there any better way to achieve this without hampering the performance?

Comment: @Roman : Updated the question with code.

Comment: The code works correctly, although because of `readLine` there will be no `^M`, `\r` characters in `line` (see the docs for  [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments: the file is read in line by line with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. The readline strips off the line break character ^M (\r) so it never makes it into the `String` that is later searched.

Answer (score -1):

How about reading char by char instead of line by line? The replacements seem trivial then.